# How do I convert this response to HTML?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I make an XMLHttpRequest and receive a response that looks like this

> \u003Cdiv class=\u0027upcoming-events\u0027\u003E\r\n      \u003Ch3 class=\u0027h3-med\u0027\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/user-calendar\u0022\u003ECalendar\u003C/a\u003EUpcoming\u003C/h3\u003E\r\n

What is this response type and how would I convert it to HTML in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to perform any conversion; these Unicode characters should be interpreted correctly as-is.

```js
var string = "\u003Cdiv class=\u0027upcoming-events\u0027\u003E\r\n \u003Ch3 class=\u0027h3-med\u0027\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/user-calendar\u0022\u003ECalendar\u003C/a\u003EUpcoming\u003C/h3\u003E\r\n";
document.body.innerHTML = string;
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```